# React component ignores dynamic element while re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, render

I have developed a react component with three div elements like below.

```
render: function(){
    return (
    <div id="div_1">
        <div id="div_2"></div>
        <div>
            Click the below button
            <a href="#">Click here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
})
```

In runtime, using jquery am inserting few elements into "div_2" div like below.

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    //Invoking global function, which is outside react
    window.loadView();
}
```

And my load view method looks somthing like below,

```
function loadView(){
   $('#div_2').html('//my elements')
}
```

Now to my surprise, when I change the status of my react component, the view is getting re-rendered but somehow the contents within "div_2" remains undisturbed. Can someone say why this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

React has its own virtual copy of the DOM, hidden somewhere. React uses this to do its magic in only updating DOM when something changed from state A to state B.

In your example, React is unaware of the changes you made with jQuery to `<div 2>`. So, as far a React knows, `<div 2>` is unchanged, so React does not update it.

I would ***strongly advise against mixing React and jQuery for updates to components***. If you want to keep your code manageable, give React the exclusive monopoly to update the DOM.

In your case, I would advise to let React only manage the inner part, like so:

```
render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        Click the below button
        <a href="#">Click here</a>
      </div>
    );
})
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div id="div_1">
    <div id="div_2"></div>
    <div id="react-only domain"></div>   // mount your ReactDOM here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `componentDidUpdate` in your case instead of `componentDidMount`.

Comment: ok.. but my doubt is, why react is not clearing the "div_2" elements while re-rendering?

Comment: Because of React dont know what happening inside elements which is not "tracking" by React render-engine. React think that "div_2" is still empty